# Retrieve interpolated desired positions from JointTrajectoryController without execution?

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-kinetic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get the result of the interpolation that the JTC does without executing it?

I have checked most of the source of the `JointTrajectoryController` but so far I haven't found anything related to the interpolation.

When sending the following trajectory:

```
header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
joint_names:
- 'joint1'
points:
- positions: [0.6]
  velocities: [-0.1]
  time_from_start: {secs: 0, nsecs: 800000000}
- positions: [0.4]
  velocities: [0]
  time_from_start: {secs: 1, nsecs: 200000000}
```

If I send these commands I can monitor the `state/desired` topic to see the result, however I'd like to get the result of the interpolation and check what the calculated desired positions will be before actually executing them on my robot.

Is this possible or am I misunderstanding something about the `JointTrajectoryController`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321070/retrieve-interpolated-desired-positions-from-jointtrajectorycontroller-without-execution?/) by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2019-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As in #q320899, I'm not entirely sure why you are doing this, but sampling of the trajectory is done [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/9bb2657b96a4ff0a1f6350f899adbf107548d313/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller_impl.h#L378), as part of [JointTrajectoryController<..>::update(..)](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/9bb2657b96a4ff0a1f6350f899adbf107548d313/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller_impl.h#L347-L349).

This makes use of [QuinticSplineSegment::sample(..)](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/24191346c909769cd02d8041bd83fcd9c83e294e/joint_trajectory_controller/include/trajectory_interface/quintic_spline_segment.h#L115) to do the actual sampling.

You could instantiate your own `JointTrajectoryController::Trajectory` and populate it with a `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory` (using [joint_trajectory_controller::internal::initJointTrajectory(..)](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/54d65413d1f1bc8ac8bed602d848c94b5e30dfb5/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/init_joint_trajectory.h#L204)) and then perform the iteration and sampling directly.

Note: most of this is in the `internal` namespace of `joint_trajectory_controller`, so not part of the public API, meaning it could change at any time and without prior notice or bw-compatibility.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-15**:\

> I'm not entirely sure why you are doing this

The goal is to create a human-like walking pattern. I want to show the visualization to experts to give feedback on the walking pattern.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-15**:
Going the way I described in my answer would embed knowledge about this being "for a visualisation" into this/these component(s). It would perhaps be better to create a visualisation/simulation configuration/variant of your application and use that (next to a configuration that runs your application with the real robot) instead of creating new components.

That should/would allow you to reuse much more of your software than creating custom components for these things at this level (or at least: that is my experience).

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-15**:
I have a simulation which can be interacted the exact same way as the physical hardware, so I could definitely use that instead. The main component of my question is to get the planned trajectory as fast as possible. I assume that running the trajectory through a simulation will only slow that down, and should have no effect on the desired trajectory, but I might be wrong on that one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way you could do this is to remap the outgoing command to a different topic, so it doesn't go to the ROS controller. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2019-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-14**:
Which topic would need to be remapped exactly? And is it possible to retrieve the calculated trajectory instantly or would you still have to wait for the execution time to finish?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2019-04-14**:
I don't recall exactly what the topic is. Probably `state/desired`. And yes, you would be able to see the whole trajectory instantly because it's published as one big message.

**Comment by [Isha Dijcks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38758/isha-dijcks/) on 2019-04-14**:
I was wondering because I usually plot the `state/desired` and it doesn't show up as one big message, or maybe it is timestamped in the future? I'll check it out, thanks!

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2019-04-14**:
Maybe the topic has 'goal' in it, because it's sending a goal to the action server